# Images not rendering in blade view after ajax call Laravel 7

Tags: php, jquery, css, ajax, laravel-7

I am working on a search filter, fetching data from db through ajax call, text data is rendering but the image is not rendering, the link is also present in console image tag, but not showing in the blade view... if I submit it through form it renders data and images as well, please guide me... Thanks
Here's my blade code:

```
                 @if (count($product)>0)    
                    @foreach ($product as $row)
                <div class="col-sm-6 col-lg-4 px-2 mb-3">
                    <div class="card shadow-sm">
                        <div class="card-img position-relative">
                            <div class="owl-carousel position-relative">
                        @if (count($row->images)>0)
                                @foreach($row->images as $images)
                                <div> <img class="w-100" height="180px" width="250" src="{{ asset('carchain_private/public/src/uploads/ImagesP'.$row->product.'/'.'u_'. $row->user_id.'/'.'qr_'.$row->id.'/' . $images->name) }}"></div>
                                @endforeach
                        @else
                                <div> <img src="{{URL::asset('src/img-market/car.jpg')}}" alt="image"> </div>
                        @endif
                            </div>
                            
                            <div
                                class="imgs-num rounded-pill bg-white light-color d-inline-flex align-items-center px-2">
                                <img class="camera-icon mr-1"
                                     src="{{URL::asset('src/img-market/camera-to-take-photos.png')}}" alt="camera icon">
                                {{count($row->images ?? '0')}}
                            </div>
                        </div>
```

Here's my controller code:

```
    $product = DB::table('manual_lovers')->select("*") 
                            ->leftJoin('users','manual_lovers.user_id','=','users.id')
                            ->leftJoin('location_manual_collectors','manual_lovers.id','=','location_manual_collectors.user_id')
                            ->leftJoin('prices_manual_collectors','manual_lovers.id','=','prices_manual_collectors.user_id')
                            ->select('manual_lovers.*','users.user_type','prices_manual_collectors.price','prices_manual_collectors.currency','location_manual_collectors.address','location_manual_collectors.latitude','location_manual_collectors.longitude')
    ->get();
    if($request->ajax()){
                $page = view('marketplace.search_results_append', compact('product'))->render();
                return response()->json(array(['page' => $page, 'count' => $count]));
            }
    here's the ajax call:
    
    <script>
       

              

$('#condition,#price_min,#price_max,#year_min,#year_max,#mileage_from,#mileage_to,#location,#latitude,#longitude,#distance_km,#search_make,#model,#search_body,#country,#color,#sort_by').on('change',function(e){
                  e.preventDefault();
                    var condition = $('#condition').val();
                    var price_min = $('#price_min').val();
                    var price_max = $('#price_max').val();
                    var year_min = $('#year_min').val();
                    var year_max = $('#year_max').val();
                    var mileage_from = $('#mileage_from').val();
                    var mileage_to = $('#mileage_to').val();
                    var location = $('#location').val();
                    var latitude = $('#latitude').val();
                    var longitude = $('#longitude').val();
                    var distance_km = $('#distance_km').val();
                    var search_make = $('#search_make').val();
                    var model = $('#model').val();
                    var search_body = $('#search_body').val();
                    var country = $('#country').val();
                    var color = $('#color').val();
                    var sort_by = $('#sort_by').val();
                    
                            $.ajax({
                beforeSend: function(){
                    $('.ajax-loader').css("visibility", "visible");
                },
    
                headers: {
                    'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')
                },
    
                url:"{{route('advanced_search')}}",
    
                method:"POST",
    
                dataType:"json",
    
                data:{
    
                    condition:condition,
                    price_min:price_min,
                    price_max:price_max,
                    year_min:year_min,
                    year_max:year_max,
                    mileage_from:mileage_from,
                    mileage_to:mileage_to,
                    location:location,
                    latitude:latitude,
                    longitude:longitude,
                    distance_km:distance_km,
                    search_make:search_make,
                    model:model,
                    search_body:search_body,
                    country:country,
                    color:color,
                    sort_by:sort_by
    
                },
    
                success:function(data) {
                    // console.log(data);
                    $('#result_count').html(data[0].count);
                    $('#search_results_append').html(data[0].page);
                },
                complete: function(){
                    $('.ajax-loader').css("visibility", "hidden");
                },
    
    
            });
    
    
    
                 });
            </script>
```

Here's the console's picture:
[image]

Here's the blade's view:
[image]

Comment: By the way (as a sidenote) `[ ... ]` is the same as `array(...)` in PHP so if you do `array([ ... ])` you're creating an array of an array which is why you need to do `data[0].page` to get the page instead of `data.page` if you just returned `[ 'page' => ..]`. Also can you check whether your image is obscured by the div? If it is then this question is more about styling and less about JS or Laravel so I would suggest you edit accordingly

Comment: All good and well. You have provided your jQuery request and it works as you prove. The problem is not in your jQuery, it's in your blade file. Have you tried with the `asset()` helper?

Comment: Try the asset()

Comment: i have updated my code and included the blade file... Sorry for late reply @apokryfos